# Expected value of the parameter $P$ of a Bernoulli having observed $s$ successes over $t$ trials, when $P$ is uniform on $[a,b]$ with $0\le a<b\le 1$

Tags: probability, estimation, bayes-theorem, beta-function, bernoulli-distribution

Using the relation between Beta and Gamma functions
$$B(m,n) = \frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$
where
$$B(m,n) = \int_{[0,1]} p^{m-1}(1-p)^{n-1}\operatorname{d}p$$
and the fact that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that
$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)! \;$$
it can easily be proved that for any $s,t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s\le t$ it holds
$$
\frac{\int_{[0,1]}p^{s+1}(1-p)^{t-s}\operatorname{d}p}{\int_{[0,1]}p^{s}(1-p)^{t-s}\operatorname{d}p} = \frac{s+1}{t+2} \;.
$$

These computations arise when we sample Bernoulli random variables in i.i.d. manner according to some random parameter $P$, which is known to be drawn uniformly on $[0,1]$, and we want to compute the expected value of $P$ having observed $s$ successes over $t$ trials, using Bayes theorem.

I wonder whether an analogous formula holds if we know in advance that $P$ is drawn according to a uniform in $[a,b]$, with $0\le a<b\le1$. In this case, the distribution of $P$ having seen $s$ successes over $t$ trials will be
$$q \mapsto \chi_{[a,b]}(q) \frac{q^{s}(1-q)^{t-s}}{\int_{[a,b]}p^{s}(1-p)^{t-s}\operatorname{d}p}$$
and hence, its expectation will be
$$
\frac{\int_{[a,b]}p^{s+1}(1-p)^{t-s}\operatorname{d}p}{\int_{[a,b]}p^{s}(1-p)^{t-s}\operatorname{d}p} = (\star) $$

I know that, "probably", asking for a closed formula for $(\star)$ is too much.

Instead, what I do hope for is that if $\frac{s}{t} \in [a,b]$ (or maybe even $\frac{s}{t} \in[c,d]$ for some $a<c<d<b$) and $t \ge t_0$, where $t_0$ is a (large) constant, then
$$\bigg|(\star)-\frac{s}{t}\bigg| \le \frac{C}{t}$$
for some universal constant $C>0$, as it was the case when $P$ was uniform in $[0,1]$, given that
$$
   \bigg|\frac{s+1}{t+2} - \frac{s}{t}\bigg| \le \frac{3}{t+2}\;.
$$

The idea is that, as long as the empirical mean $s/t$ is in the acceptable range $[a,b]$ (or, if boundary effects are problematic, as long as $s/t$ is in a subinterval $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$ with $a < c < d < b$) and the sample size $t$ is big enough, we should expect the prior of $P$ to weight less and less and the posterior to converge to a distribution highly concentrated around $s/t$, and hence its expectation should be close to this value.

I haven't managed to find a meaningful relation (such as the one relating Beta and Gamma) to obtain this result and, actually, I'm not sure what could be a viable strategy to prove this conjecture.

Any ideas, hints, pointers to the literature?

Comment: you can work out a solution based on the appendix B you find here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.12107.pdf